# How values and keys get assigned in a dictionary using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I was running this code through python tutor, and was just confused as to how the keys and values get switched around. I also was confused as to what value `myDict[d[key]]` would correspond to as I'm not sure what the `d` in `[d[key]]` actually does.

```
def dict_invert(d):
    '''
    d: dict
    Returns an inverted dictionary according to the instructions above
    '''

    myDict = {}
    for key in d.keys():
        if d[key] in myDict:
            myDict[d[key]].append(key)
        else:
            myDict[d[key]] = [key]
    for val in myDict.values():
        val.sort()
    return myDict

print(dict_invert({8: 6, 2: 6, 4: 6, 6: 6}))
```

Comment: 'd' is the argument of the function... i.e. the dictionary you're inverting.

Comment: `d['key']` would correspond to actual value mapped with key that value will be new key for `myDict` dictionary

Comment: While the code you show isn't *wrong*, it would be more elegant to use `for key, value in d.items()` rather than getting just the keys and then later needing to use `d[key]` to get the value (especially since you need to do it twice).

Comment: Post the output. It should help illuminate.

Answer (score 1):

In your function `d` is the dictionary being passed in. Your code is creating a new dictionary, mapping the other direction (from the original dictionary's values to its keys). Since there may not be a one to one mapping (since values can be repeated in a dictionary), the new mapping actually goes from value to a list of keys.

When the code loops over the keys in `d`, it then uses `d[key]` to look up the corresponding value. As I commented above, this is not really the most efficient way to go about this. Instead of getting the key first and indexing to get the value, you can instead iterate over the `items()` of the dictionary and get `key, value` 2-tuples in the loop.

Here's how I'd rewrite the function, in what I think is a more clear fashion (as well as perhaps a little bit more efficient):

```
def dict_invert(d):
    myDict = {}
    for key, value in d.items():       # Get both key and value in the iteration.
        if value in myDict:            # That change makes these later lines more clear,
            myDict[value].append(key)  # as they can use value instead of d[key].
        else:
            myDict[value] = [key]      # here too
    for val in myDict.values():
        val.sort()
    return myDict
```

Answer (score 1):

The function you are showing inverts a dictionary `d`. A dictionary is a collection of *unique* keys that map to values which are not necessarily unique. That means that when you swap keys and values, you may get multiple keys that have the same value. Your function handles this by adding keys in the input to a list in the inverse, instead of storing them directly as values. This avoids any possibility of conflict.

Let's look at a sample conceptually first before digging in. Let's say you have

```
d = {
    'a': 1,
    'b': 1,
    'c': 2
}
```

When you invert that, you will have the keys `1` and `2`. Key `1` will have two values: `'a'` and `'b'`. Key `2` will only have one value: `'c'`. I used different types for the keys and values so you can tell immediately when you're looking at the input vs the output. The output should look like this:

```
myDict = {
    1: ['a', 'b'],
    2: ['c']
}
```

Now let's look at the code. First you initialize an empty output:

```
myDict = {}
```

Then you step through every key in the input `d`. Remember that these keys will become the values of the output:

```
for key in d.keys():
```

The value in `d` for `key` is `d[key]`. You need to check if that's a *key* in `myDict` since values become keys in the inverse:

```
if d[key] in myDict:
```

If the input's value is already a key in `myDict`, then it maps to a list of keys from `d`, and you need to append another one to the list. Specifically, `d[key]` represents the value in `d` for the key `key`. This value becomes a key in `myDict`, which is why it's being indexed like that:

```
myDict[d[key]].append(key)
```

Otherwise, create a new list with the single inverse recorded in it:

```
else:
    myDict[d[key]] = [key]
```

The final step is to sort the values of the inverse. This is not necessarily a good idea. The values were keys in the input, so they are guaranteed to be hashable, but not necessarily comparable to each other:

```
for val in myDict.values():
    val.sort()
```

The following should raise an error in Python 3:

```
dict_invert({(1, 2): 'a', 3: 'b'})
```

Comment: I've answered the three questions OP has clearly stated: 1) How do the keys and values get switched around? 2) What does `myDict[d[key]]` correspond to? 3) What does the `d` in `[d[key]]` actually do? My goal was to answer in such a way that a person who would have those questions in the first place would have a chance to understand, which I believe involves a lot of background material. If something specific is unclear, please let me know. I'll be happy to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

`myDict[d[key]]` takes value of `d[key]` and uses it as a key in `myDict`, for example

```
d = {'a': 'alpha', 'b': 'beta'}
D = {'alpha': 1, 'beta': 2}
D[d['a']] = 3
D[d['b']] = 4
```

now when contents of `d` and `D` should be as following

```
d = {'a': 'alpha', 'b': 'beta'}
D = {'alpha': 3, 'beta': 4}
```

Answer (score 0):

`d` is the dictionary you are passing into the function

```
def dict_invert(d)
```

When you create

```
myDict[d[key]] = d
```

Its meaning is

```
myDict[value of d] = key of d
```

Resulting in

```
myDict = {'value of d': 'key of d'}
```

Comment: It's getting appended to a list

Comment: @MadPhysicist " was just confused as to how the keys and values get switched around. I also was confused as to what value "myDict[d[key]]" would correspond to as I'm not sure what the 'd' in '[d[key]]' actually does." - OP